# Grouping columns and summing column-wise to keep one line per groupement

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame structure:

| ID | conception_date | birth_date | med_1 | med_2 | med_3 | med_4 | ... | med_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | xxxx | xxxx | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... |  |
| A | xxxx | xxxx | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... |  |
| A | xxxx | xxxx | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... |  |
| B | xxxx | xxxx | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... |  |
| B | xxxx | xxxx | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... |  |
| B | xxxx | xxxx | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... |  |
| B | xxxx | xxxx | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... |  |
| C | xxxx | xxxx | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... |  |
| C | xxxx | xxxx | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... |  |

I would like to group people by their `ID`, `conception_date` and `birth_date` in order to keep one line per person while summing medications per column per groupement. So the structure would become:

| ID | conception_date | birth_date | med_1 | med_2 | med_3 | med_4 | ... | med_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | xxxx | xxxx | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |  |  |
| B | xxxx | xxxx | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| C | xxxx | xxxx | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |  |

Comment: Please provide better sample data and explain what you have tried thus far.

Comment: Is the `N_person` row supposed to be a "total row"; and if so, why is it in the original, unsummarized dataset?  And is `med_N` a rowwise sum of `med_1` through `med_4`, or is it just a placeholder, as if to say "there are `N` columns of the form `med_*`?

Comment: @Greg No N_person and N_med indicate that they go to Nth id and Nth medication as I have more than 4 medications and more than 3 IDs. I updated the data frame to include only 3 IDs and 4 medications to avoid confusion

Comment: `library(dplyr); your_data |> summarize(across(everything(), sum), .by = c(ID, conception_date, birth_date))`